# Vim find pattern unless it matches

Tags: search, vim

I have a space delimited set of hex values and want to find `/[0-9a-f]\{2\}` unless the value is `00`. For example, if the buffer is

```
00 00 00 00 18 00 00 00
```

the pattern should match the `18` but not the white space or the `00`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with the following regular expression:

```
\x\{2}\(00\)\@<!
```

Explanation:

- `\x`:     hex digit: [0-9A-Fa-f]
- `\{2}`:   matches two of the preceding atom
- `\(00\)`: an atom containing `00`
- `\@<!`    nothing, requires NO match behind

For more information, see:

- [`:help pattern.txt`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#pattern.txt)

Comment: Or a shorter variant: `\v\x{2}(00)@<!`

Comment: Or the much shorter variant: `\v(00)@!\x\x` {par 12}